# Uninstall "Microsoft Edge Update" permanently

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-11, microsoft-edge, system-administration

There are three programs related to *Microsoft Edge* that come installed by default in *Windows 11*:

1. `Microsoft Edge`
2. `Microsoft Edge WebView`
3. `Microsoft Edge Update`

– I was able to uninstall **Microsoft Edge** with the following commands:

`cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\*\Installer`

`.\setup.exe -uninstall -system-level -verbose-logging -force-uninstall`

– I was able to uninstall **Microsoft Edge WebView** with the following commands:

`cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\*\Installer`

`.\setup.exe --uninstall --msedgewebview --system-level --verbose-logging --force-uninstall`

– When I started to uninstall **Microsoft Edge Update**, I couldn't find a similar way to uninstall it like the above. I searched the web in depth. Even professional uninstallers (e.g. *IObit Uninstaller*, *Revo Uninstaller*) couldn't get it!

So I am asking help from a great poweruser who help me to uninstall it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third-party applications such as [Zoom](https://zoom.us/) use [Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) (I've observed Zoom running as many as eight EdgeWebview2 processes!). If you remove WebView2, you will disable Zoom and other applications dependent on it.

The easiest *and safest* thing to do with MS Edge, if it's not wanted (nor its pseudopodia to Bing and other MS "services") , is to [**disable** it](https://woshub.com/uninstall-disable-microsoft-edge/), and to **disable the update mechanism**. One could open *services.msc* and manually disable the three critical update services, as shown below, *and* set GPO to disable Edge browser itself, but a third-party tool such as [Sordum's Edge Blocker](https://www.sordum.org/9312/edge-blocker-v1-7/) makes it convenient to turn MS Edge *and* it's update services on or of with a single click. This does not affect WebView2, however, so Zoom runs well with MS Edge disabled.

[image: Block Edge Update]

Why *not* uninstall Edge? Because it would likely be reinstalled after any major Windows OS update, and so far, I've found *disabling Edge services* persists past the update -- and if at a later time they're reenabled, then Edge Blocker can fix that issue with a click. Also, there are poorly designed web sites that work properly *only* with Edge, so when corporate policy forces one to use such a site, Edge can be enabled again with a click -- and then disabled after use.